# Iterate through check boxes in layout

Tags: android-layout

I have a series of check boxes in my activity.xml file and want to iterate through them in order to check whether they are checked or not. How can this be done?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create variables in the java code of the activity like

```
private CheckBox checkBoxOne;
```

then later at or after creating the activity you link it to the xml checkboxes like

```
checkBoxOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxOne)
```

assuming a checkbox is called "checkBoxOne" in the xml file.
After having done that, you can ask the checkbox if it is checked by

```
if (checkBoxOne.isChecked()) {
    // here do what has to be done
}
```

Comment: I want to ITERATE through check boxes. There are 13 of them and I am not willing to write code for each one separately. That's simply repitition

Comment: You have to put them into anything iterable, an array or a list maybe… Then you can iterate through its members, the CheckBoxes. There is no different possibility, I think… Please provide some code or xml if you are interested in further help. Thanks